# Glassfish service log file grows without bound

Tags: logging, glassfish

Our application runs on Glassfish 3.1.2.2.  We have noticed that the following log file grows without bound:

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\bin\domain1ServiceService.err.log
```

This file seems to just echo the normal logging that also goes into the main server.log file.  So I think it is completely redundant and unnecessary.  The problem is that over the course of a couple of days it grows to 15+ GB in size and eventually consumes all remaining space on the drive, which causes a lot of problems for Glassfish (and Windows).

How can I stop this file from being produced by Glassfish, or at least limit its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish uses [winsw](http://kenai.com/projects/winsw/) as service logging implementation on Windows.

You can configure the logging in the file `(domain)service.xml`, in your case this should be:

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\bin\domain1ServiceService.xml
```

You can set different logmodes. The default is to append to the file until server restart.

You can change the log mode in this line:

```
<logmode>reset</logmode>
```

to `roll`, this will rotate the log file on server restart. Unfortunately you can't configure it to `reset` or `roll` the log files at server runtime, only on server start/restart.

**As a workaround**, you can turn off the logging by removing `--verbose` from this line:

```
  <startargument>--verbose</startargument>
```

This will turn off the logging, **but it will also cause that the microsof service control can't properly communicate with GlassFish**, e.g. you can start the server via the service control but you can't stop it, you'll have to kill the process manually.

**See also:**

- [Bug 4246 - Winsw creates unmanaged stdout and stderr logs](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4246)
- [Glassfish 3.1 as a windows 7 service creates unmanaged stdout and stderr logs](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-31-windows-7-service-creates-unmanaged-stdout-and-stderr-logs)
- [GLASSFISH-16720 Launcher Should have a Watchdog Mode](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16720)

Comment: I also tried using <logmode>rotate</logmode>.  Since starting the server with that log mode about 24 hours ago, the log file has only grown to about 5 MB, whereas previously it would have grown to over 15 GB in that same time period.  I would have assumed "rotate" would mean to rotate out old log files once they get to a certain size, but I don't see any rotated log files in that directory- only the current one.

Answer (score 1):

I am using glassfish 3.1.2.2 and had this issue. My solution was to replace the service wrapper provided by glassfish (an early version of winsw) in the deployed application with the 1.16 version of winsw and configured that so that no logfiles are generated by winsw (except the wrapper log which is small in my case). I have downloaded winsw from here:

http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/com/sun/winsw/winsw/1.16/

**Steps:**

Stop the service if it is running.

Replace the service exe (as an example I replaced this file:
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\myServices\bin\myServicesService.exe)
with the 1.16 version of winsw (of course had to rename the file).

Then open the file xxxService.xml 
(e.g. C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\myServices\bin\myServicesService.xml) 
and change the logmode by setting

```
<logmode>none</logmode>
```

(from `<logmode>reset</logmode>` which is the default)

Also add a `<stopexecutable>` node which is required by this version of winsw. Copy the value from the `<executable>` tag. Here is an example:

`<stopexecutable>C:/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin.bat</stopexecutable>`

Finally start the service.